# android listview trying to set new adapter but views dont refrash

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

Im building an app that loads news posts.
i have a custom adapter and when the application launch I set the listview the adapter and fill it with data.
the problem that I have to sources of data, the first is "popular news" and the second "recent news" that the user can switch between on click.
the default is "recent news". when the user clicks on popular news I clear the adapter and the arrayList, fill it with new data and attach it to new list view.

my problem is that when I do it, nothing is shown on screen, and only when I start to scroll the screen fill again with data.
how can I avoid from the situation then user click on the "popular news" and see nothing to the list view?

this is and adapter class:

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (position == 0) {
        return 0;
    } else if (position == 1)
        return 1;
    if (position > 1 && position < 5) {
        return 2;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }

}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 3;
}


@Override
public View getView(final int position, final View convertView,
        ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    final ViewHolder holder;
    int type = getItemViewType(position);
    // if first time you load this line
    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        holder = new ViewHolder();

        if (type == 0) {
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gap_between_main_post_to_top,
                    null, true);
            row.setTag("0");
            return row;
        }

        if (type == 1 || type == 3) {
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_main_post, null, true);
            holder.title = (TextView) row
                    .findViewById(R.id.textViewMainTitle);
            holder.pubDate = ((TextView) row
                    .findViewById(R.id.mainPostDate));
            holder.postImage = (ImageView) row
                    .findViewById(R.id.imageViewMain);
            holder.postLikes = ((TextView) row
                    .findViewById(R.id.postLikesMain));
            holder.postCommunts = ((TextView) row
                    .findViewById(R.id.postCommuntsMain));
            holder.postShares = ((TextView) row
                    .findViewById(R.id.postSharesMain));
            holder.like_share_communt = (LinearLayout) row
                    .findViewById(R.id.share_like_communt);
            holder.postLikesImage = (ImageView) row
                    .findViewById(R.id.imageViewLike);

            row.setTag(holder);
        } else if (type == 2) {
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_main_sub_post, null, true);
            holder.title = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textViewSub1);
            holder.pubDate = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.postDateSub);
            holder.postImage = (ImageView) row
                    .findViewById(R.id.imageViewSub1);
            holder.like_share_communt = (LinearLayout) row
                    .findViewById(R.id.share_like_communt);
            holder.postLikes = ((TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.postLikes));
            holder.postCommunts = ((TextView) row
                    .findViewById(R.id.postComments));
            holder.postShares = ((TextView) row
                    .findViewById(R.id.subPostShares));
            holder.postLikesImage = (ImageView) row
                    .findViewById(R.id.imageViewLike);
            row.setTag(holder);
        }

    } else {
        if(row.getTag().toString().equals("0"))
            return row;
        else
        holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
    }

    .......
```

this is the onClick method:

```
private OnClickListener changeNewsSourceListener = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == popularNews) {
            adapter.clear();
            postsArray.clear();

            sort = "popularity";
            pageNumber = 1;
            addItems();

        }

    }
};
```

and this is where the adapter fills with data (the addItems method):

```
    public void addItems() {

    new RoboAsyncTask<ArrayList<Post>>(this) {
        protected void onPreExecute() {

        }

        public ArrayList<Post> call() throws Exception {

            try {
                String url = context.getResources().getString(
                        R.string.servicesUrl);
                url += "?page=" + pageNumber + "&sort=" + sort;
                return DataPosts.getInstance(context).getPosts(url);
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                Log.i("exption", e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();
                throw new Exception(e.getMessage());
            }

        }

        protected void onSuccess(java.util.ArrayList<Post> result) {
            swipeLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            postsArray.addAll(result);
            mainListView.removeAllViewsInLayout();
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        };

        protected void onException(Exception e)

        {
            Log.i("exption", e.toString());
        }
    }.execute();

}
```

Comment: what do you mean? its in the third paragraph..

Comment: Try assigning the ArrayList to the adapter again (new Adapter with ArrayList as parameter again), and call setAdapter on the ListView. Also, try removing adapter.clear() and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: hey...ive tried what youve said but theres no different...